# org.jetbrains? What is it?

Tags: android, openvpn

I recently cloned the ics-openvpn project: https://code.google.com/p/ics-openvpn/source/checkout

But when I opened the project, it gave me some errors considering these lines not being resolved:

```
import org.jetbrains.annotations.NotNull;
import org.jetbrains.annotations.Nullable;
```

I tried searching it on the internet, but I got no clear answer. 
So my question is: What is 'jetbrains'? How do I resolve this?

Thanks

Comment: www.jetbrains.com for one :) as far as the library goes, I cannot give an answer. Guessing it's related to the projected being built with intelliJ (ics = Ice Cream Sandwich?) Don't consider this as an answer - I'm just providing my thoughts.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

[`@Nullable`](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/nullable-and-notnull-annotations.html#nullable) and [`@NotNull`](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/nullable-and-notnull-annotations.html#notnull) annotations introduced in [IntelliJ IDEA](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IntelliJ_IDEA) for catching [`NullPointerException`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/lang/NullPointerException.html)'s (NPE's) through the Constant Conditions & Exceptions and @Nullable problem inspections.

The `org.jetbrains.annotations` project is open-source, [hosted at GitHub](https://github.com/JetBrains/java-annotations). A [few other annotations](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/annotating-source-code.html) are included: `@Nls` & `@NonNls` for localization, `@PropertyKey` for resource bundles, and `@TestOnly` for testing.

To download the library of annotations, see the [GitHub page](https://github.com/JetBrains/java-annotations).

Maven:

```xml
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.jetbrains</groupId>
    <artifactId>annotations</artifactId>
    <version>16.0.2</version>
</dependency>
```

Answer (score 2):

To solve this issue

> **Android The import org.jetbrains cannot be resolved**

Download the last version of annotations jar
http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/com/intellij/annotations/12.0/annotations-12.0.jar

and paste into `/libs` folder of your project:
[image]